# Correct configuration of WindowBytesStoreSupplier

Tags: apache-kafka-streams, spring-cloud-stream, spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka

What are correct `WindowBytesStoreSupplier` configuration values for a `JoinWindows.of(Duration.ofMinutes(5))`?

This

```kotlin
fun mangelJoinStoreSupplier(): WindowBytesStoreSupplier = Stores.inMemoryWindowStore(MangelJoinStore.NAME, Duration.ofMillis(86700000), Duration.ofMinutes(5), true)
```

results in:

```
org.apache.kafka.streams.errors.StreamsException: Window settings mismatch. WindowBytesStoreSupplier settings InMemoryWindowBytesStoreSupplier{name='mangel-join-store', retentionPeriod=86700000, windowSize=300000, retainDuplicates=true} must match JoinWindows settings JoinWindows{beforeMs=300000, afterMs=300000, graceMs=85800000} for the window size and retention period
```

Comment: The condition is: https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/trunk/streams/src/main/java/org/apache/kafka/streams/kstream/internals/KStreamImplJoin.java#L223-L224

Comment: I found it later on through debugging, but it'd be great to have it in the api docs

Comment: Feel free to open a PR! It's always good to improve the docs!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For

```kotlin
JoinWindows.of(Duration.ofMinutes(5)).grace(Duration.ZERO)
```

is

```kotlin
Stores.inMemoryWindowStore(MangelJoinStore.NAME, Duration.ofMinutes(10), Duration.ofMinutes(10), true)
```

the correct supplier

Comment: Is this another question? Might be better to edit your original question.